# Strange format duration with date-fns for simple case

Tags: node.js, date-fns

I have a strange format case with date-fns and formatting duration. If somebody have an idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
function formatDuration(duration) {
  return duration >= 60000 * 60
    ? format(new Date(duration), "hh 'h', mm 'min', ss 'sec'")
    : duration >= 60000
      ? format(new Date(duration), "mm 'min', ss 'sec'")
      : format(new Date(duration), "ss 'sec'");
}
```

What I expect:

```
formatDuration((59 * 60 + 59) * 1000); // '59 min, 59 sec'
formatDuration((60 * 60) * 1000); // '01 h 00 min, 00 sec'
```

What I get:

```
formatDuration((59 * 60 + 59) * 1000); // '59 min, 59 sec'
formatDuration((60 * 60) * 1000); // '02 h 00 min, 00 sec'
```

In the second case, there is an extra hour appearing from nowhere. I don't understand where the problem is. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your code has three possible code paths. One for 3600000 and up, one for between 60000 and 3599999, and one for 59999 and below. So: which of those three code paths is going wrong? (because once you know that, now you can remove those from your post: they are not relevant to the problem you're asking about. And you can lift the problematic codepath out of `formatDuration`, we don't need that wrapping to poke at the problem anymore)

Comment: (And the biggest red flag here is that if you're trying to format a duration, why are you creating _dates_? A one hour duration has _nothing_ to do with January 1st, 1970, in the UTC timezone. You want to format timestamps, not datetimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of you were true that using Date was not a good idea. Manipulating number was more successfull. Here is my solution to my problem:

```
function formatDuration(duration) {
  if (!duration) {
    return '';
  }

  const durationSeconds = duration / 1000;

  const hours = Math.floor(durationSeconds / 3600);

  const restHours = durationSeconds % 3600;

  const minutes = Math.floor(restHours / 60);

  const seconds = restHours % 60;

  const hoursPart = hours > 0 ? `${hours} h, ` : '';

  let minutesPart;
  if (hours > 0) {
    if (minutes > 0) {
      minutesPart = `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')} min, `;
    } else {
      minutesPart = '00 min, ';
    }
      } else {
    if (minutes > 0) {
      minutesPart = `${minutes} min, `;
    } else {
      minutesPart = '';
    }
  }

  let secondsPart;
  if (hours > 0 || minutes > 0) {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      secondsPart = `${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')} sec`;
    } else {
      secondsPart = '00 sec';
    }
  } else {
    if (seconds > 0) {
      secondsPart = `${seconds} sec`;
    } else {
      secondsPart = '';
    }
  }

  return `${hoursPart}${minutesPart}${secondsPart}`;
}
```

Maybe there is a more simple solution than this one but its working well and it's ok for all my cases.

Tested with this, all green:

```
describe('duration_format', () => {
  const cases = [
    [2, '2 sec'],
    [9, '9 sec'],
    [14, '14 sec'],
    [23, '23 sec'],
    [36, '36 sec'],
    [47, '47 sec'],
    [51, '51 sec'],
    [59, '59 sec'],
    [60, '1 min, 00 sec'],
    [61, '1 min, 01 sec'],
    [82, '1 min, 22 sec'],
    [154, '2 min, 34 sec'],
    [887, '14 min, 47 sec'],
    [30 * 60 + 22, '30 min, 22 sec'],
    [59 * 60 + 22, '59 min, 22 sec'],
    [59 * 60 + 59, '59 min, 59 sec'],
    [60 * 60, '1 h, 00 min, 00 sec'],
    [12 * 60 * 60 + 45 * 60 + 22, '12 h, 45 min, 22 sec'],
  ];

  test.each(cases)('%s to %s', (duration, humanReadable) => {
    expect(formatDuration(duration * 1000)).toBe(humanReadable);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you create a `new Date(duration)`, `duration` is interpreted as a timestamp, i.e. from 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 UTC.

But date-fns takes that Date object as is, and interpretes it in the locale of the current JS engine, e.g. in UTC+1 if you are in metropolitan France in winter. So midnight UTC is already 1am in UTC+1. Hence your extra 1 hour.

If you handle only durations, you could just divide your number of milliseconds appropriately, instead of going through the headache of converting dates and timezone.

Another solution could be to make sure to create your date in the local timezone as well, e.g. by adding its offset:

```js
const offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

const date = new Date(duration + offset);

// Then...
format(date, "hh 'h', mm 'min', ss 'sec'")
```

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/OZF7PiCjZfmCEHpN?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Note that this might still bring strange effects, as it would assume a duration from 01-Jan-1970 (not a leap year, gap across DST switch, etc.).

I guess it would return a wrong result again as soon as you try running it in DST, because the offset would then take DST into account, but a short duration would fall before the DST had kicked in. Hence the created Date would have incorrect time.

Comment: As you mentioned yourself. This will give you wrong results once you are in european DST, because it will correct the duration by 2 hours instead of only 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not to misuse the `Date` object (which is a *timestamp*) as duration, because whatever `hh` resolves to, depends on the timezone your process is currently running in (or you have a formatting library, that can be told to only use UTC). From your result, it seems you are currently in a timezone UTC+1. When you do `new Date(3600000)` this is actually`1970-01-01T01:00:00Z` (ie UTC). But this is also `1970-01-01T02:00:00 GMT+1` in your local timezone. Try executing `new Date(3600000).toLocaleString()` in node or your browser's developer console and you will see, the result contains `02` for the hours.  And this `02` is what `date-fns` uses to format the date, because it formats timestamps according to your local timezone.

Furthermore, this approach will also lead to wrong results if your duration gets longer than 12/24 hours, because depending on whether you use a 12 (`hh`) or 24 (`HH`) hour clock, the hour component can never be greater than 12 or 24 respectively. You are using `hh`, thus the longest duration you can format is 12 hours.

The safest approach is use a library, that has an explicit type for durations and supports formatting them with custom format strings. If you don't have such a library, you can also calculate the hours, minutes ... yourself from the duration. This way you are safe from timezones and overflows.

```js
let 
  hin = 75, min = 23, sin = 54, msin = 123, //input hours, minutes, seconds 
  duration = (hin * 3600 + min * 60 + sin) * 1000 + 123; //duration in milliseconds
  
  
let h = Math.floor(duration / 3600000);  //get the number of full hours
duration %= 3600000;  //remove the full hours from the duration
let m = Math.floor(duration / 60000);  //the the number of full minutes from the remaining duration
duration %= 60000;  //remove the full minutes from the duration
let s = Math.floor(duration / 1000); //get the number of full seconds
duration %= 1000;   //remove the full seconds from the duration
let ms = duration;  //the remaing duration are the milliseconds

console.log("input:", hin, min, sin, msin);
console.log("result:", h, m, s, msin);  //this should give the same values as the input

let 
  hs = `${h}`.padStart(2, "0");  //use the string.padStart function to add a leading 0 if needed
  ms = `${m}`.padStart(2, "0");  //use the string.padStart function to add a leading 0 if needed
  ss = `${s}`.padStart(2, "0");  //use the string.padStart function to add a leading 0 if needed 
  mss = `${ms}`.padStart(3, "0");  //use the string.padStart function to add a leading 0 if needed (ms has  three places)
  
let durationformat = h > 0
  ? `${hs} h ${ms} min ${ss} sec` 
  : `${ms} min ${ss} sec` ;
  
console.log("formatted:", durationformat)
```

Another way to get the (somewhat) correct hours, minutes and seconds is parsing them from the result of `toISOString()`, but again with the drawback, that you cannot represent durations longer than 24 hours this way.

```js
let 
  hin = 14, min = 23, sin = 54, msin = 123, //input hours, minutes, seconds 
  duration = (hin * 3600 + min * 60 + sin) * 1000 + 123; //duration in milliseconds

let 
  isostring = new Date(duration).toISOString(),
  [_, h, m, s, ms] = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})/.exec(isostring) ?? [];
  
console.log("input:", hin, min, sin, msin);
console.log("iso:", isostring);
console.log("result:", h, m, s, ms);
  
  
//do the formatting as in the snippet above
```

Or if you want to stick with `date-fns`, you should make sure you are formatting the correct timestamp. Manipulating the duration with the current UTC offset like [@ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77776009/3776927) suggests will give you wrong results when you enter DST, because then it will correct the duration by 2 hours, but the UTC offset on 1970-01-01 is only one hour. An easy way to fix this is to use

```
const offset = (new Date(0)).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
const date = new Date(duration + offset);
```

instead. Note the `0` I passed to the `new Date(0)` constructor. This will always give you the correct offset of your timezone on Jan 1st 1970, and thus correct the duration by the correct amount of time.

An alternative solution, is passing a `string` instead of a `Date` to the [`format`](https://date-fns.org/v3.2.0/docs/format) function  of `date-fns`. This `string` is then parsed to a `Date`. And the crucial point is, if the `string` doesn't contain any timezone information, `date-fns` will assume the timezone the process.

So how to construct a correct timestring? Easy, just use [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and cut away the trailing `Z` (which carries the timeszone information)

```
format(new Date(duration).toISOString().slice(0, -1), "hh 'h', mm 'min', ss 'sec'")
```

Why does this work? `new Date(3600000).toISOString()` will create the following string `1970-01-01T01:00:00.000Z`, ie Jan 1st 1970, 1:00 AM in *UTC timezone*. If you throw away the `Z` (denoting the UTC timezone) you get `1970-01-01T01:00:00.000` which `date-fns` will interpret as Jan 1st 1970 1:00 AM in your *current timezone*, and thus printing the correct value for `hh`

But as both of these variants are kind of hacky, I'd still suggest to use something that explicitly handles *durations* and is able to format them accordingly or calculate hours, minutes and seconds yourself.

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're encountering with the unexpected extra hour in the second case is due to the way the format function from date-fns library works. When you pass a duration directly to the format function, it treats it as a timestamp (number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970), rather than a duration.

To correctly format durations, you can use the formatDuration function provided by the date-fns library itself. Here's an updated version of your code that uses formatDuration:

```
import { formatDuration } from 'date-fns';

function formatDurationCustom(duration) {
  const milliseconds = duration % 1000;
  const seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  const hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  return formatDuration({
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    milliseconds,
  });
}

console.log(formatDurationCustom((59 * 60 + 59) * 1000)); // '59 min, 59 sec'
console.log(formatDurationCustom((60 * 60) * 1000)); // '1 hr, 0 min, 0 sec'
```

In this updated code, we're using the formatDuration function from the date-fns library to correctly format the durations. We calculate the separate units of the duration (hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds) and pass them as an object to formatDuration. The function will handle formatting the duration based on the provided units.

With this approach, you should get the expected output:

basic
Copy

> 59 min, 59 sec
>
> 1 hr, 0 min, 0 sec

Make sure you have the date-fns library installed and imported correctly in your project for this code to work.

Comment: Did you try your code? 1) The units int the output are not named as `h`, `min` and `sec` as op requires but as `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` and there doesn't seem to be any possibility to customize that wording, except changing the locale. Don't know how important that is for OP, though. 2) If you pass an object like `{ hours: 1, minutes: 0, seconds: 0}` to `dateFns.formatDuration`, it won't include the zeros in the result string. Ie the result will just be `1 hour`. You need to pass the repective option `zero` in the `FormatOptions` parameter